# Depressingly Happy?

Tags: meaning

I saw a status message that said Depressingly Happy, that makes no sense whatsoever to me. Are they happy or depressed? Being happy surely can't ever be depressing?

Comment: To me that means that the person is so happy they make others depressed.

Comment: Where did you see this status message?  It's likely facetious, but more context would be helpful.

Comment: As James said, Someone that is _depressingly happy_ is so happy that makes others depressed. Something (a situation, a song, etc) that is _depressingly happy_ is supposed to make you feel good, but actually depresses you.

Comment: @Claire - What James said may quite possibly be the case, but an example would help us confirm that.

Answer (score 3):

This particular confusion has nothing to do with the English language. "Depressingly happy" isn't an idiomatic expression you've never heard before; it does in fact mean (at least grammatically) that this particular happiness is causing depression.

There are two general senses I have seen this used:

- Describing conflicting emotions. "I thought I'd be sad when my children moved out, but I find myself depressingly happy." Here the speaker is disappointed in herself for not feeling a loss to the degree she expected to.
- Depression at another's happiness. "My ex and his new girlfriend are depressingly happy." Here the speaker is grieved because her ex's happiness implies there is no longer hope of reunion.

Comment: I think I understand now, It was a status message on my sons facebook page, someone who had gone to work in the Caribbean last year, he was supposedly going to be away for 3 years but has recently moved back to his home town, after reading the two examples, I would think he means depressed for whatever reason his employment in the Caribbean ended early, but happy to be home.